# Get User Roles in GET method

Tags: rest, jwt, asp.net-identity, angular8, asp.net-core-2.2

I'm using an api REST in .net Core 2.2 implemented with JwtToken and an Angular 8 Application.
I'm trying to get the user Role to show it to the admin and give the possibility to edit this user role, but the role doesn't appear

```
    [HttpGet]
    [Authorize]
    //GET: /api/UserProfile
    public async Task<Object> GetUserProfile()
    {
        string userId = User.Claims.First(c => c.Type == "UserId").Value;
        var user = await _userManager.FindByIdAsync(userId);
        var role = await _userManager.GetRolesAsync(user);
        return new
        {                
            user.Email,
            user.UserName,
            user.Role,
        };

    }
```

Comment: I am not sure if you just made a typo in your question or not, but there is no "Role" property on the user in Asp.Net Identity.  Perhaps you meant to say "role" instead of "user.Role" in your anonymous return?

Answer (score 0):

As you know, user doesn't have a `role` property. Also each user has many roles. If you always have one role for each user, so select user's role like this:

```
    [HttpGet]
[Authorize]
//GET: /api/UserProfile
public async Task<Object> GetUserProfile()
{
    string userId = User.Claims.First(c => c.Type == "UserId").Value;
    var user = await _userManager.FindByIdAsync(userId);
    var role = await _userManager.GetRolesAsync(user);
    return new
    {                
        user.Email,
        user.UserName,
        role = role.FirstOrDefault() ,
    };

}
```